# how to sum a structure array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, recursion

I have a structure array in which every value is a number, I would like to do the sum of these structures.

*Example:*

S is structure array and every element has the same structure

```
S(1).a = 1
S(1).b.c = 1
S(1).b.d = 2

S(2).a = 2
S(2).b.c = 3
S(2).b.d = 4
```

sum(S) should be a structure 'SUM' with fields :

```
SUM.a = 1+2 = 3
SUM.b.c = 1+3 = 4
SUM.b.d = 2+4 = 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find any matlab function to achieve this, so I programmed this function:

```
function out = sumStruct(in)
% sum structure field per field

    if isstruct(in)
        for f = fields(in)'
            out.(f{:}) = sumStruct([in.(f{:})]);
        end
    else
        out = sum(in);
    end
end
```

If I do SUM = sumStruct(S), I get what I want.

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer with `f{1}` instead of `f{:}` (twice), and `.'` instead of `'`